# how to wait for HTTP requests to get response in a loop before its processes to next step

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

how to wait for HTTP requests to get response.I'm trying to make API calls several time using loop but I did not get exact data the values ill-received based on the execution time of the API call means the values, not arranged according to request.required value like o,1,2,3,4 (index) and its return values like 2,1,3,4.

```
    var l=0 ; 
  for (var k=0;k<this.imagesdataarray.length;k++ ){

   this.http.post('http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/DesignerProject/Create',{
      name: this.imagesdataarray[k].projecttitle,
      designerCategoryID: this.imagesdataarray[k].categoryid,
      userID: this.userid
      
    })
    .subscribe(res => { 
   
        this.data1=res;
        this.imagesdataarray[l].projectid=this.data1.result.id;
        l++;
    }
    );
   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `forkJoin()` for something like this to run an array of observables.

Here's an example on StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t7phj1?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
 array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(
      this.array.map(i =>
        this.http.get<any[]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${i}`)
      )
    ).subscribe(response => console.log(response));
  }
```

Comment: This is the way I would do it, my answer above with async/await will likely not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the operation in the subscribe block to perform synchronous operations, you could utilize an async/await pattern for the anonymous function within the subscribe block. Here is an example:

```
.subscribe(async (res) => { 

    await this.data1=res;
    await this.imagesdataarray[l].projectid=this.data1.result.id;
    l++;
});
```

This may still not resolve your problem considering the completion of the call is dictated outside the scope of the subscription. My suggestion would be to utilize rxjs and try building a series of request with the [forkJoin operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) and then iterate through each the subscription from there.