# How i assign value of http get response to sub array in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular8, httpresponse

I am trying to push data to sub-array (nested array) the data that comes from the response is good but did not push the value to a subarray but at the end, I got an empty array.

```
export class images{
 
  designcategory:any;
  insidecontent:boolean=true;
  projecttitle:any="No Title";
  projectid:any;
  imagesnamearray: imagesnames[] = [];
  categoryid:any;


}
export class imagesnames{
  public image:any;
  public imagename:any;
  public imageid:any;
  public completeimagepath:any;

}
export class AddProjectComponent implements OnInit {

image = new images;
imagesdataarray=[]; // this is my image data array and i push images to 
                    //  object in this array to create dynamic row 

ngOnInit(): void {
 for (var j=0;j<this.imagesdataarray.length;j++){
 
    this.http.get("http://api.interiordesigns2020.com/api/services/app/ImageProject/GetAll?ProjectID="+this.imagesdataarray[j].projectid+"&MaxResultCount="+10000).subscribe( (res:any) =>{
    this.data=res;
    for  (var k in this.data.result.items.length){
      this.imagesdataarray[j].imagesnamearray.push({image:this.data.result.items[k].imageFiles,imagename:this.data.result.items[k].imageName,imageid:this.data.result.items[k].id ,completeimagepath:this.globalshare.websiteurl+"/images/UploadedWork/"+this.userid+"/"+this.imagesdataarray[j].projectid+"/"+ this.data.result.items[k].imageName});
  }
  });
}
}, 2000);
}
}
```

Comment: Please update the question with details of imagesdataarray as well. Is it and array or object?

Comment: the question is updated, please provide me any suggestions

Comment: the details of imagesname array is added

Comment: Calling an api inside a for loop wont get you the desired result. Coz http calls are asynchronous. By the time the first api call response becomes available, your for loop might complete the execution. Thats thats the reason you are seeing the change only to the last array element.

Comment: i even not get the value of the last array element the array seems is totally empty

Comment: imagesdataarray=[]; is initialised as empty and hence your for loop wont execute.

Comment: You've ask the similar question over the past few days: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553233/how-to-iterate-through-an-api-response-and-assign-response-value-to-nested-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536114/how-to-wait-for-http-requests-to-get-response-in-a-loop-before-its-processes-to and also pretty sure https://stackoverflow.com/users/15366359/syed-matiullah is the you on another account with similar questions. Did you not applied or attempt to use any of the answers to your solution?

Comment: @penleychan- I have only that account some issues solved in some scenario but some did not and I don't get any solutions

Comment: penleychan - please suggest me a permanent solution or lecture for that so I am able to solve that issues.